# Is the laptop compatible with SATA?

Tags: cpu, sata

I'm currently considering buying a laptop DELL Inspiron 5759-0261. For some reason I can't find its specification on the [vendor site](http://www.dell.com), but the [local store](http://technopoint.ru/product/2ed4d571bb7239f3/173-noutbuk-dell-inspiron-5759-0261-serebristyj-sale/characteristics/) tells that it has Pentium 4405U processor. I'm very confused by the fact, that there is no any I/O specification for 4405U on the [intel site](https://ark.intel.com/products/89611/Intel-Pentium-Processor-4405U-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz) (unlike, e.g. [N3710](https://ark.intel.com/products/91830/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3710-2M-Cache-up-to-2_56-GHz)). I will really apreciate any help with finding an up-to-date service guide for the laptop. However, the main question so far, **is the laptop compatible with any SATA interface**?

Comment: You would be hard pressed to find any laptop made in the last 6-8 years or so that doesn't have SATA... Also, the FIRST link I clicked on after googling "DELL Inspiron 5759-0261" clearly stated this laptop uses a 2.5" 500GB 5400RPM SATA drive. http://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/dell/dell_notebook/DELL-Inspiron-5759-5759-0261-Pent-4405U-4-500-DVD-RW-WiFi-BT-Linux-173-289-kg_290389.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that model does use SATA connectors for the drives. Just about every laptop and desktop does these days (although I'm sure there are exceptions).

For reference: [specifications and service manuals for Inspiron 5759](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-17-5759-laptop/manuals) (it's in the specifications pdf under storage).

Comment: The main problem is that there is no such configuration in the manuals (with specified porcessor).

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev it definitely has SATA with that processor. SATA is more of a motherboard feature than a processor feature, so I'm surprised it was listed as a feature of any of the processors.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops have SATA connectors for storage, with a bracket for 2.5" hard drives or SSDs.  Some are z-height restricted (the height in millimeters).  SATA is a very common standard, although it's starting to be replaced by PCIe , m.2 , and u.2 connector standards.  When in doubt, ask the vendor instead of asking a third party question/answer board :) .